# Can it returns null? (this.Result ==Result.OK)

Tags: c#, null, return

Can this code return null?

```
(this.Result == Result.OK)
```

Can this line (or a similar one) return anything except than `true` or `false` (e.g. null)?

Comment: if value of 'this' is NULL then this code will surely break

Comment: I think it returns boolean `:)`

Comment: If might return [FileNotFound](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx) every once in a while.

Comment: What you need... `if(this.Result == Result.OK) return null;` ??

Comment: `this` will never be `null`

Comment: @xxMUROxx `this will never be null` **usually** but it can be :)

Comment: @xxMUROxx how sure of that are you? http://pastie.org/8516778

Comment: @MarcGravell I know that already:)

Comment: I think it can only returns true/false or you get an exception :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
(this.Result == Result.OK)
```

OK; let's take this piece by piece:

```
this.(anything)
```

That can fail if `this` is `null` - which it *never should be*, but [theoretically can be if you are evil](http://pastie.org/8516778) - so we could fail with a `NullReferenceException`.

```
this.Result
```

if that is a property accessor (a `get`), then it could fail in any way it likes - it could throw an exception.

```
Result.OK
```

now; if this is an `enum`, it is just a `ldc` - but if this `.OK` is actually a static property accessor, it can certainly fail with any exception it likes.

```
this.Result == Result.OK
```

We need to know what `.Result` returns; if we *assume* that it returns a `Result` (we don't know that), then we still need to know what `Result` is: if it is an enum it'll be a direct numeric equality check; if it is a nullable-enum, "lifted" equality rules apply, but still resolve cleanly. If it is a custom type that overloads `==`, then anything could happen and any exception could result.

But here's the crazy: `==` does not need to return a `bool`:

```
public static int operator ==(int x, Foo foo)
{
    return 0; // DO NOT EVER DO THIS
}
public static int operator !=(int x, Foo foo)
{
    return 0; // DO NOT EVER DO THIS
}
```

If you the `Result` type is custom, then `(this.Result == Result.OK)` can return **anything it wants**:

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new P().Test();
    }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    public void Test()
    {
        var x = (this.Result == Result.OK);
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name); // Int32
    }
}
public class Result
{
    public static Result OK { get { return null; } }
    public static int operator ==(Result x, Result y)
    {
        return 42; // DO NOT EVER DO THIS
    }
    public static int operator !=(Result x, Result y)
    {
        return 0; // DO NOT EVER DO THIS
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to consider that something obscure like a `ThreadAbortException`, `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverflowException` could happen ***at any time***.

But in sane conditions: yes, it can only result in a `bool` result.

Comment: @AgnelKurian IL instruction to load a constant value - for example, `ldc.i4` (aka hex 20) followed by 4 bytes loads a constant `int` onto the stack (there are special codes for commonly used numbers, or numbers that fit in a single byte, etc)

Comment: Thanks. Might want to rephrase "If you the Result type is custom".

Comment: You missed the case where it never returns due to a while(true) :)

Comment: @mcintyre321 d'oh! I guess there's always another kind of crazy

Comment: The tarpits of [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.110).aspx) are filled with [innocent developer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoAPKt7kbD0) skeletons...

Comment: I would say the exception parts of your answer are irrelevant personally. If things throw exceptions I wouldn't say they were returning so my logic was it can only return boolean but of course it could not return at all. I hadn't though about overloading == though. That is a bit evil. ;-)

Comment: @Chris if I was being **really** evil, I would have overloaded `true` too.

Comment: Wow! I never knew you could overload true... I'm trying to work out if that is cool or terrifying...

Comment: @Chris finally we can create that `struct TriBool` - mwahahahaah

Answer (score 5):

The `==` operator will return true or false at all times. That is a `boolean`.

It should be noted that the "or another" in your question can indeed return something other than true or false. Unless you tell us what the other you have in mind is we can't answer that.

This answer assumes that the expression does return something. As Marc Gravell points out exceptions may stop it returning at all (depending on how you consider returning).

Also Marc kindly pointed out that `==` can be overloaded. It is almost certainly a bad idea to do so and change the return type but it seems it is theoretically possible.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'd also not use the word simply there. You have proved it it not correct but I don't think that's in a simple case at all. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As `==` is comparison operator,this statement always return a `Bool`

Answer (score 4):

No, [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53k8ybth.aspx) can only returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement itself will return a `bool` true or false.

The object involved:

`this.Result`

Could potentially be null, perhaps this is what you're referring to when you ask whether it can return `null`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible outcomes.

1. The line is executed and returns true
2. the line is executed and it returns false

Comment: `this` is null? huh? Are you talking about corner case?

Comment: whoopsie, forgot the property

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right, That's what I asked `Are you talking about corner case?`

Comment: If you remove that point 3, I'll remove my downvote and upvote you. because that is false and misleading

Comment: Well, I have undeleted my own answer, because of MarcGravell adding something. Might as well make it right